# How can I sort a nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a nested list of the form:

```
list = {{4., -18., 19.}, {3., 18., -5.}, {-5., -8., -15.}, {-20., 7., -16.}, {10., -13., -7.},
        {-12., -9., 17.}, {17., 19., 5.}, {-16., 9., 15.}, {11., -5., -14.}, {18., -10., 13.},
        {-3., 11., 12.}, {-6., 17., -8.}, {-18., 14., 1.}, {-19., -15., 10.}, {12., 18., -19.}, 
        {-8., 4., 7.}, {-8., -9., 4.}, {7., 17., -15.}, {12., -7., -14.}, {-10., -11., 8.},
        {2., -15., -11.}, {9., 6., 1.}, {-11., 20., -17.}, {9., -15., 13.}, {12., -7., -17.},
        {-18., -2., 20.}, {20., 12., 4.}, {19., 11., 14.}, {-16., 18., -4.}, {-1., -17., -19.},
        {-13., 15., 10.}, {-12., -14., -13.}, {12., -14., -7.}, {-7., 16., 10.}, {6., 10., 7.},
        {20., 14., -16.}, {-19., 17., 11.}, {-7., 1., -20.}, {-5., 12., 15.}, {-4., -9., -13.},
        {12., -11., -7.}, {-5., 19., -8.}, {1., 16., 17.}, {20., -14., -15.}, {13., -4., 10.},
        {14., 7., 10.}, {-5., 9., 20.}, {10., 1., -19.}, {-16., -15., -1.}, {16., 3., -11.},
        {-15., -10., 4.}, {4., -15., -3.}, {-10., -16., 11.}, {-8., 12., -5.}, {14., -6., 12.},
        {1., 6., 11.}, {-13., -5., -1.}, {-7., -2., 12.}, {1., -20., 19.}, {-2., -13., -8.}, 
        {15., 18., 4.}, {-11., 14., 9.}, {-6., -15., -2.}, {5., -12., -15.}, {-6., 17., 5.},
        {-13., 5., -19.}, {20., -1., 14.}, {9., -17., 15.}, {-5., 19., -18.}, {-12., 8., -10.}, 
        {-18., 14., -4.}, {15., -9., 13.}, {9., -5., -1.}, {10., -19., -14.}, {20., 9., 4.}, 
        {-9., -2., 19.}, {-5., 13., -17.}, {2., -10., -18.}, {-18., 3., 11.}, {7., -9., 17.},
        {-15., -6., -3.}, {-2., 3., -13.}, {12., 3., -2.}, {-2., -3., 17.}, {20., -15., -16.},
        {-5., -17., -19.}, {-20., -18., 11.}, {-9., 1., -5.}, {-19., 9., 17.}, {12., -2., 17.},
        {4., -16., -5.}};
```

I wish to first sort each sublist based on the absolute values(e.g. `{4., -16., -5.} => {4., -5., -16.}`) and then sort the sublists based on the first followed by the second element (based on absolute values for both the cases).

For example, considering the first `5` sublists the sorted list should be

```
listSorted5 = {{3., -5., 18.}, {4., -18., 19.}, {-5., -8., -15.},
               {-7., 10., -13.}, {7., -16., -20.}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
list // Map[SortBy[Abs]] // SortBy[#, ({Abs@#[[1]], Abs@#[[2]]} &)] &
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, `TableForm[
 data // Map[SortBy[Abs]] // 
  SortBy[#, ({Abs@#[[1]], Abs@#[[2]], Abs@#[[3]]} &)] &]` is what is I needed.

Comment: `list2 = SortBy[SortBy[#, Abs] & /@ list, Abs]`

Answer (score 3):

```
sort = Map[SortBy @ Abs] /* SortBy[Abs @* Most]

sort @ list
```

> {{-1., -5., -13.}, {-1., -5., 9.}, {1., -5., -9.}, {1., 6., 9.}, {1., 
>     6., 11.}, {1., -7., -20.}, {1., 10., -19.}, {-1., 14., 20.}, {1., 
>     14., -18.}, {-1., -15., -16.}, {1., 16., 
>     17.}, {-1., -17., -19.}, {1., 19., -20.}, {-2., -3., 17.}, {-2., 
>     3., -13.}, {-2., 3., 12.}, {-2., -6., -15.}, {-2., -7., 
>     12.}, {-2., -8., -13.}, {-2., -9., 
>     19.}, {2., -10., -18.}, {2., -11., -15.}, {-2., 12., 
>     17.}, {-2., -18., 20.}, {-3., 4., -15.}, {3., -5., 
>     18.}, {-3., -6., -15.}, {-3., 11., 12.}, {3., -11., 16.}, {3., 
>     11., -18.}, {4., -5., -16.}, {4., 
>     7., -8.}, {4., -8., -9.}, {-4., -9., -13.}, {4., 9., 20.}, {-4., 
>     10., 13.}, {4., -10., -15.}, {4., 12., 20.}, {-4., 14., -18.}, {4., 
>     15., 18.}, {-4., -16., 18.}, {4., -18., 19.}, {5., -6., 
>     17.}, {-5., -8., -15.}, {-5., -8., 12.}, {-5., -8., 19.}, {-5., 9., 
>     20.}, {-5., 11., -14.}, {-5., 12., 15.}, {5., -12., -15.}, {-5., 
>     13., -17.}, {5., -13., -19.}, {-5., -17., -19.}, {5., 17., 
>     19.}, {-5., -18., 19.}, {6., 7., 10.}, {-6., -8., 17.}, {-6., 12., 
>     14.}, {7., -9., 17.}, {-7., 10., -13.}, {-7., 10., 16.}, {7., 10., 
>     14.}, {-7., -11., 12.}, {-7., 12., -17.}, {-7., 12., -14.}, {-7., 
>     12., -14.}, {7., -15., 
>     17.}, {7., -16., -20.}, {8., -10., -12.}, {8., -10., -11.}, {9., \
>   -11., 14.}, {-9., -12., 17.}, {-9., 13., 15.}, {9., 13., -15.}, {9., 
>     15., -17.}, {9., 15., -16.}, {9., 17., -19.}, {-10., 
>     11., -16.}, {-10., 13., 18.}, {10., -13., 
>     15.}, {10., -14., -19.}, {10., -15., -19.}, {11., 14., 
>     19.}, {-11., -17., 20.}, {11., 
>     17., -19.}, {11., -18., -20.}, {-12., -13., -14.}, {12., 
>     18., -19.}, {-14., -15., 20.}, {14., -16., 20.}, {-15., -16., 20.}}

Also

```
sort2 = SortBy[Abs @* Most] @* Map[SortBy @ Abs]

sort2 @ list == sort @ list
```

> True